# Low Memory Usage, low CPU usage but threads are exhausted, application not taking requests

Tags: java, spring, gateway, saga

I have a java spring based application which is written in saga design pattern to work as GATEWAY layer (backend for front end, BFF). It often happens that this layer service runs out of threads even when dashboards shows normal CPU and memory usage. Our http client configuration for requesting to core services has socket timeout set to 10 seconds which is working fine (tested). Anything I might be missing?

Comment: How did you determine it "has run out of threads"? AFAIK that's not a thing that can happen.

Comment: found that it in dynatrace per pod(kubernetes) current thread usage dashboard, also user complained for 3-5 minutes that they could not login to the application. Rolling restarting of application helped resolving the problem.